# display:flex and positioning my elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries, flexbox

I am struggling to know which elements i should apply the display:flex; rule and which to apply flex-wrap:wrap; to to achieve the design structure i want.

I understand the media queries and how to apply rules for option above and below a certain screen size - can media queries also override flex rules?

I have a `<div =“col-4” class=“sidebar”` along a `<div=“col-8” class=“ img-box”` .I want them next to one another in a row if the screen size is over 480px, but i want the `<div =“col-4” class=“sidebar”` to stack underneath `<div=“col-8” class=“ img-box”` on screen size smaller than 480px, and for them both to display 100% when stacked. Can anyone give me guidance on the CSS for this please? tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no reason to actually use flexbox here. However, if you really want to use there's a straight-forward way using `flex-direction`.

Usually `display: flex;` is used on parent elements (containers), but you can nest as many flex containers as you need.

Regarding your use case, you can easily achieve the desired responsive layout like so:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){
  .container{
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

Please note that this assumes your markup looks like this:

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="col-8">
      ... 
  </div>

  <div class="col-4">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I've made [a pen](https://codepen.io/danmindru/pen/ORwyqA) for you with an example, just so you get the full picture.

---

Secondly, I'm not sure what effect you expect `<div=“col-8”>` to have, but there's no such thing in CSS / HTML. The way to make this work is to use it as a class, i.e.: `<div class=“col-8 img-box”>`. Then in your CSS, you need to add something similar to:

```
.col-8{
  width: calc(100% / 12 * 8);
}
```

(also added that to the pen)

Comment: thanks Dan - i missed out my class! Ooops,  I think i had been at my desk too long! Thanks for your advice, it's really helped me become clearer  on how to apply the rules now :)

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` is always applied to the *container*  element and automatically makes all direct child elements in that container *flex-items*.

`flex-wrap:wrap;` is also applied to the *container* and lets the flex items overflow to the next line or column (depending on flex-direction) when they don't fit in one line/column.

It has nothing to do with media queries, but of course you *can*  put these into media queries for flex containers and items to be treated differently on different screen sizes.

Concerning your last paragraph: It would be better to post that as a separate question - it has nothing to do with flex.  But something is wrong in your code here: `<div =“col-4” class=“sidebar”` can't be right - probably you mean `<div class="sidebar col-4">` ?  Same for the other one...

Comment: Thank, yes you are right, my code was wrong, i meant exactly as you said ( i am new to css, if you couldn't already tell

Comment: Thank for your reply - yes you are right, my code was wrong, i did indeed mean ```<div class="sidebar col-4">```. Thanks for clarifying the```display: flex``` and ```flex-wrap``` it is all making much more sense now, you've helped !